# Url doesn't changing when redirecting to another action method in same controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

In myC# MVC project, i have a 'Home' controller like below,

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return this.View();
}

public ActionResult LoadVideo()
{
    return RedirectToAction("LoadVideoExt");
}

public ActionResult LoadVideoExt()
{
    return this.View();
}
```

And my problem is,  my url is like this `http://localhost:51241/Home/Index` when running the code. I have a button in my `Index` view to call `LoadVideo` from there I am redirecting to another action and load that page `LoadVideoExt`. The process is working fine but the final view is not rendering and also my url is not changing accordingly (as I am expecting `http://localhost:51241/MyJob/LoadVideoExt`). I am a bit confused here. Could someone help me out or point me in the right path?

Sample code attached below.

View (Index.cshtml)

```
function uploadMedia() {

        linkUrl = '@Url.Action("LoadVideo", "Home", new { area = string.Empty })';


        var formData = new FormData($('#fromIndex')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: linkUrl,
            type: 'Post',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () { },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(0);
            },
            xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                    // Progress code if you want
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "DefaultMultipleParams",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{state}"
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

View (LoadVideoExt.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoadVideoExt";
}

<h2>Gotcha!</h2>
```

Let assume my url is like this `http://localhost:51241/MyJob/Index` when running the code. I have a button in my 'Index' view to call `LoadVideo` from there I am redirecting to another action and load that page `LoadVideoExt`. The process is working fine but the final view is not rendering and also my url is not changing accordingly (as  I am expecting `http://localhost:51241/MyJob/LoadVideoExt`). I am a bit confused here. Could someone help me out or point me in the right path?

Comment: The code you have shown **will** generate `../MyJob/LoadVideoExt`. If its not, its due to code you have not shown us

Comment: Updated the question, added the code as am running now for testing!

Comment: Your making an ajax call. Ajax calls never redirect (the whole point of them is to stay on the **same** page)

Comment: So if i  call the url directly - '@Url.Action("LoadVideo", "Home", new { area = string.Empty })';   or a form submit will it work?

Comment: Create a link so that it makes a GET to your method. There is no point using ajax if you ant to redirect to another page.

Comment: yup.. it works.. thanks for the tip.. am a bit curious to know, is there any other work around method while using ajax call to make it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154833/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-krizte).

Comment: okay.. are you available now?